# How to remove pages from a PDF while leaving the document otherwise unchanged

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have a PDF book that I want to remove a few pages from to reduce the file size. My normal solution to this didn't work, and when I tried others they introduced new problems:

- I usually use PDF Arranger for this, which is normally a great tool. However, when I try it on this particular document I get an error I've never seen before (invalid literal for int() with base 8: b'228')
- I can use pdftk to remove the pages, but the file size of the resultant document is more than double that of the original, which defeats the purpose of removing the pages in the first place
- I can also use the Print to File command to remove the correct pages, but then I get a huge margin around the pages, with a smaller font and more whitespace, making the file harder to read

As you can see, it's surprisingly tricky to remove pages while otherwise leaving the document the same. Any advice on other solutions, or figuring out what's going on with these, would be much apreciated!

Comment: Have you tried https://community.coherentpdf.com?

Comment: Hadn't heard of it! I downloaded it but couldn't figure out how to install it. I found the cpdf executable for Linux x64, but when I run it from the terminal I just get a license warning.

Comment: Type `--help` or see the examples on the website: `cpdf in.pdf 1-3,12-end -o out.pdf`

Comment: I can't get the cpdf command to be recognized by the terminal.

Comment: You have said that you can run it in your previous post. It's not the terminal that recognizes the commands. To run pdf cd to `Linux-Intel-64bit` or `Linux-Intel-32bit` and run it `./cpdf`

Comment: I said I found the executable. When I try to run it like you suggest I only get the following:

For non-commercial use only
To purchase a license visit http://www.coherentpdf.com/

Comment: Re-read my comment https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580305/how-to-remove-pages-from-a-pdf-while-leaving-the-document-otherwise-unchanged?noredirect=1#comment1080389_580305

Comment: That's not helpful. The command doesn't work, I can't install it to make it work and I can't find any relevant help file.

Comment: You don't need to install it. Invoke help with `./cpdf --help`. And, as I already said, look into examples posted on the website.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite strange that `pdftk` yields a bigger document in your case. Have you tried the *exact* following command, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17713684/7009806)?

```
pdftk infile.pdf cat 1-r2 output outfile.pdf
```

(please note that you can change the page selection, following your needs, by specifying multiple ranges as stated in a comment from the link I point to)

If, for some reason, there is no way to avoid `pdftk` yielding bigger files, you might want to try `pdfjam`, following that example:

```
pdfjam infile.pdf <page ranges> --landscape -o outfile.pdf
```

But bare in mind that `pdfjam` might want to add extra margins in order to fit a printed page format, unlike `pdftk`.